# SQL Join queries

Tags: sql, join

I am beginner in SQL, could you please help me write a query to:

- find the name of lecturer who is also a participant in one course
- find 4 courses with the most participants

The tables are:

```
- Lecturer [LecturerID (PK), name]
- Course [CourseId (PK), LecturerID, name]
- Participant [ParticipantID (PK), CourseID(PK)]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like homework.  What have you tried?

Comment: Well I'm trying to understand how does the join etc work. I want to write a simple system to learn SQL and I've got stack with this problem...

Comment: These aren't two queries I'd choose to start learning joins. More like two to see whether you had learnt them. I'm also certain that just givng you the sql isn't going to teach you anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to learn how joins work, it would be more beneficial for us to help you create the SQL yourself.  The basic format for a join is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.joinID = table2.joinID
```

I would approach this in 3 steps:

1. Write a basic SELECT statement that will return the joined table data
2. Modify the SQL to only show "the name of lecturer who is also a participant in one course"
3. Starting again with the basic SELECT statement from step 1, modify the SQL to only show "4 courses with the most participants"

These will end up being 2 different queries.

If you want to get a start on it, and get stuck, we can help you along, but it would not help you learn it if we just gave you the SQL.  Try writing a little of it, and post what you have when you are stuck.

Comment: To do the first task, would be it correct?
select name from Lecturer 
join Course on Course.LecturerID = Lecturer.LecturerID
join Participant on Participant.CourseID = Course.CourseID
where Lecturer.LecturerID = Participant.ParticipantID

Comment: That's a good start.  Do you have a working database you could play with?  I'm creating a SQLFiddle you could try out to test your queries.   Also, I'm guessing there is also a 'STUDENT' table?  Right now, we have to assume that the 'PARTICIPANT' table contains references to a fourth table.

Comment: I have to go for just a little bit, but will come back shortly to check on how you're doing.  Here is a SQLFiddle where you can test your query, and start to play around with editing it:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59788/1

Comment: I just ran your query in the SQLFiddle I created, and it is returning the right result, but you did need to be more specific on the SELECT name, because both Lecturer and Course had a name column.  So, if you change SELECT name to SELECT Lecturer.name, it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
select L.name from lecture L join participant P on L.id=P.id 

select C.cid from course C join participant P
ORDER BY P.cid DESC
LIMIT 4;
```

Hopefully it helps you

Comment: Shouldn't be there any count statement?

Comment: sorry yeah.It should be count(p.cid) DESC LIMIT 4.Thanks